# Avro - sample input

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I have an Avro schema as follows

```
{
  "doc": "Sample schema to help you get started.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "specversion",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "event",
      "type": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "communicationMessage",
            "type": {
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "id",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "default": null,
                  "name": "additionalInfo",
                  "type": [
                    "null",
                    {
                      "fields": [
                        {
                          "default": null,
                          "name": "nationalId",
                          "type": [
                            "null",
                            "string"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "default": null,
                          "name": "productNameArabic",
                          "type": [
                            "null",
                            "string"
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      "name": "additionalInfo",
                      "type": "record"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "name": "communicationMessage",
              "type": "record"
            }
          }
        ],
        "name": "event",
        "type": "record"
      }
    }
  ],
  "name": "example",
  "namespace": "com.example",
  "type": "record"
}
```

I am trying to produce data into Kafka topic but receiving error.
Below is the sample input:

{"specversion": "1.0","event": {"communicationMessage": {"id": "message123","additionalInfo": {"additionalInfo": {"nationalId": "1234567890","productNameArabic": "example"}}}}}

Error as follows

```
Error: cannot decode textual record "com.example.example": cannot decode textual record "com.example.event": cannot decode textual record "com.example.communicationMessage": cannot decode textual union: cannot decode textual map: cannot determine codec: "additionalInfo" for key: "additionalInfo" for key: "communicationMessage" for key: "event"
```

Comment: Please show your producer command and the full stacktrace of the error

Comment: Also, why is there `additionalInfo` twice and nested in each other?